# Windows Recovery

Tags: data-recovery, toshiba-laptop, partition-recovery, system-recovery

Can I use a recovery disk created on a Lenovo to recover windows 8.1 Toshiba Satellite.  The Lenovo is also windows 8.1.  I recently accidentally installed Linux Mint on the hard drive and removed windows.  I have extremely important data on I need for school.

Comment: "I have extremely important data on I need for school." Not any more. Restore disks typically are tailored to specific hardware, so there's no guarentee it would work, and chances are pretty 'good' you lost your data.

Comment: The *restore disk" contains only information about installed software. To recover files you would need something like [GetDataBack](https://www.runtime.org/data-recovery-software.htm), which work by trying to find "file-like-chunks" in the file system. **But** you "accidentally" managed to change the file system AND overwrite huge part of the physical media. So .. in short: there is almost no chance that you can recover any files.

Comment: Did you run Lenovos Backup and Restore on Windows a) to create the restore media an b) to create a backup?

Comment: @hakre no I didn't do n e thing yet,  am asking first

Comment: Could test disk be used to some how restore the windows partition?  It was portioned before,  as I said with both Ubuntu and windows

Comment: Depending on how important the data is, shutdown the laptop immediately (if it not already is), remove the power-plug and remove the battery so you don't power it up in error. Tomorrow on monday contact a firm that is specialized in data recovery from a written over partition. They will consult you with the further proceedings if any.

Comment: How expensive are these services,  if applicable to me?

Comment: That will be told to you in consulting. Note: Only you get professional support with this issue, must not mean that any data can be recovered.

Comment: Thnx man, I'll give it a try

Answer (score -1):

You can always recover a computer to Windwos 8.1 cd with a "New Installation".

There is only one problem. If you have installed Linux Mint on the Harddrive-Partion where your Windwos 8.1 system was, you maybe will not get the data back.

Always when you install a new operating system on your Computer, the OS before and the data gets deleted.

Comment: And once the data gets deleted,  it can't be recovered!?  Not even by professional recovery service?

Comment: Recuva and many other free datarecover tools are ideal for that http://alternativeto.net/software/recuva/